# Two Step Cluster Analysis with categorical variables

Tags: clustering

Can I use two step cluster analysis if I have only either continuous or categorical variables? I understand it can deal with a mixture, but I don't know if it is suitable to use for just one type.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "two step cluster analysis"?

Comment: I have copied this off a website. "Two-step cluster analysis is more of a tool than a single analysis.  It identifies the groupings by running pre-clustering first and then by hierarchical methods.  Because it uses a quick cluster algorithm upfront, it can handle large data sets that would take a long time to compute with hierarchical cluster methods.  In this respect, it combines the best of both approaches.  Also two-step clustering can handle scale and ordinal data in the same model.  Two-step cluster analysis also automatically selects the number of clusters"

Comment: Yes, it is suitable to use just one type.